# How change PickerView delegate from one controller to another one?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview, uiapplicationdelegate

With the storyboard I've built one ViewController1 with an "Add" button. Click on add display a PopoverView (in ViewController2) with only a Picker within.

So my PickerView's delegate is in ViewController 2 but I want it in ViewController1... 
Is there a  easy way to do this so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewController1.h file, change your interface header to this;

```
@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>;
```

That makes your ViewController1 in charge of the delegates. Then add the methods you want in the ViewController1.m file. Also, set the delegate of the UIPickerView to your instance of ViewController1 with this:

```
[yourPickerview setDelegate:ViewController1];
```

Comment: How this can help me to have delegate in ViewController 1 ?
By doing so, I'll have delegate in ViewController 2 instead of ViewController 1, no ?

UPDATE: I juste want my delegate in ViewC1 instead of ViewC2

Comment: read my edit, otherwise tell me more about what's wrong and what you've done. Put up some code :)

Comment: Img gonna try, come back in few minutes

Comment: Not working...

In ViewController1.h:

    `@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>`
In ViewController1.m:

   ` - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;}

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return ([categoryName count])-1;}

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  
    return [categoryName objectAtIndex:row];
    }`

Comment: In ViewController2.h:

`@interface PopOverViewController : UIViewController{`
   ` __weak IBOutlet UIPickerView *categoryPicker;`
`}`

In ViewController2.m:

    `- (void)viewDidLoad`
    `{`
    `ViewController *vc;`
    `[categoryPicker setDelegate:vc];`
    `[super viewDidLoad];`
    `}`

Comment: Sorry for indent but I can't reply as answer to my own question because I've not enough reputation.

Comment: Error message:

2012-05-05 23:40:48.327 Interface[302:f803] -[PopOverViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c3ae30
2012-05-05 23:40:48.343 Interface[302:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PopOverViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c3ae30'

Comment: Ok, I've fixed my issue. I've forgotten to init ViewController.

Comment: Good to hear. Next time, just edit your post, it's easier to read. And dont forget to set the question to solved.

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewController1 prepareForSegue method, try this:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"])
{
    ViewController2* vc2 = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc2.pickerView.delegate = self;
}
```

It basically assigns the delegate of the pickerview to ViewController1 before the segue is finished being called.

This of course is assuming your pickerview is setup as a property.

Comment: Thanks for help. Problem solved. Where can I tag this subject as solved ? Im new here :p

Comment: Just click the check mark next to the answer that fixed it =)